# Hebrew for ice - and other "new" words

Tags: hebrew, aramaic, translation

After reading [MB OC 301:17:65](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=161) (thanks, [YDK](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/is-it-actually-forbidden-to-push-a-wheelchair-outside-of-an-eruv-on-shabbat/7800#7800)!) I am baffled by a nagging question regarding Modern Hebrew and Biblical Hebrew. [Eliezer Ben-Yehudah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Ben-Yehuda) is known to have revitalized Hebrew, in part by taking Biblical and post-Biblical (often Mishnaic and/or Rabbinic) Hebrew words, and sometimes Aramaic words, and adapting them to modern uses. But there are words that are not new to the world, and certainly could not have been new to our ancestors, which he apparently adapted from the classical sources because he could not find evidence of them there but found similar words that could be made to apply. The example I'm trying to understand is the Hebrew word for "ice".

In the Mishnah Berurah above why did the M"B need to describe ice as "water which has frozen"? Furthermore, why did he have to Hebraicize the Aramaic word for "freeze"? Is there no classical Hebrew word for "ice" or even "freeze"? According to http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0131.htm "קֶרַח" translates as "frost". According to [http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/גלד](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%93) the word "גלד" is Aramaic for "freeze" and Hebrew (presumably modern) for "scab". I have also seen elsewhere in my search today that "גלד" is also used in the context of congealing (I believe in Hebrew).

Is there no other classical Hebrew source for a word that translates directly as "ice"? It seems almost inconceivable that our ancestors did not have a word for this. Is it just that the word is unknown because our sources are limited to Biblical and post-Biblical writings?

Comment: Does anyone know why the titlebar for this question is "aramaic - Hebrew for ice - and other "new" words"? Something off with the meta tags or something?

Comment: I think it adds the first tag that's not already in the question title.

Comment: @Alex I suspect the algorithm may be more sophisticated than that, perhaps choosing the most "interesting" tag, or something.

Comment: @Isaac, @Alex pretty much got it correct, except that "first" is defined as "most interesting", which is defined by "most used".

Comment: I'm going to assume that the answer to my ultimate question, "Is it just that the word is unknown because our sources are limited to Biblical and post-Biblical writings?" is most likely, "yes", and it seems everyone who has answered (so far) feels the same way.

Comment: @SethJ they definitely had the word קרח meaning ice at least by the times of the rishonim; so "post-biblical" Hebrew does have the word.

Answer (score 10):

There is at least one possible usage of קרח in Tanach in the sense of "ice" - Ezek. 1:22 (כעין הקרח הנורא), which Targum Yonasan translates as גליד חסין, "strong ice." [Metzudos also renders some other instances of קרח as גליד, the Talmudic word for ice (from the root גלד, as you noted), as in Mikvaos 7:1 and Bava Basra 20a.]

To follow up on msh210's point, though: if (supposedly) the Eskimos need lots of words for snow, then people living in the temperate climate of Eretz Yisrael may have needed only one word meaning "frozen water" generally, and then the words כפור and ברד to describe particular kinds of frozen precipitation. Alternatively, the word גליד may have existed in Biblical times too and just wasn't recorded. Which isn't as odd as it sounds: cats are pretty common in the Land of Israel too, but there is no word for "cat" in Tanach (the word חתול is attested only in Mishnaic and later Hebrew).

Comment: The חתול thing was mentioned to me once by a guy who knows tanach by heart, in the form of a riddle: How many times does it mention dogs or cats in tanach? Answer: dogs twice and cats none.

Comment: @jake: not sure where he got the idea that dogs are mentioned only twice. By my count there are 32 mentions (including two in one verse, I Kings 21:19).

Comment: @Alex, Sorry I meant in the Torah, not in Tanach. Then it's just לא יחרץ כלב לשונו, and לכלב תשליכון אותו, I think.

Comment: @jake: Also לא תביא... ומחיר כלב.

Comment: @jake, Alex, and _Nach_ has _shegel_, also a dog, IIRC.

Comment: @Alex, Good point.

Comment: @msh210: only according to one explanation in the Gemara (Rosh Hashanah 4a). The Gemara seems to end up saying that שגל means the queen consort, though, and that's also how the commentaries explain each of the verses that the Gemara quotes there (Ps. 45:10, Dan. 5:2-3,23, and Neh. 2:6).

Answer (score 4):

Although קרח can refer to frost, in certain instances it refers to ice and is translated as such by Artscroll as well as Mechon-Mamre, like [Iyov 37:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2737.htm), [Yechezkel 1:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1201.htm), and [Tehillim 147:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e7.htm).

Also, I noticed that that mechon-mamre translates יתלכדו of [Iyov 38:30](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2738.htm) as "frozen" even though Artscroll translated it as "imprisoned". On the other hand, Artscrol translates מים במוצק of Iyov 37:10 as "water becomes solidified", while mechon translated it as "straitened".

Even if there are words for ice and freezing in biblical hebrew, though, I can see why Mishna Berura would be reluctant to use them, as they're quite obscure, and likely not to be understood by the average reader.

Comment: In Tehillim, though, it seems more likely that it means frost, rime, or something of the sort. A sheet of ice could hardly be described as כפתים ("like broken pieces"), after all.

Comment: @Alex, _mashlich karcho k'fitim_ can't be sleet?

Comment: @msh210: could be, but then what would כפור be? If anything, it seems more likely that קרח would mean frost (which is common at night, as in Yaakov's complaint) rather than sleet (which is not).

Comment: @Alex, I don't see what's difficult about broken pieces of ice.

Comment: @Alex, makes sense.

Comment: @jake: nothing, but would you describe Hashem as משליך ("throwing") them?

Comment: @Alex, Why not?

Comment: @jake: because ice isn't "thrown down" from the sky in pieces (except for hail, sleet, etc.); it forms in place, on the ground or the surface of a body of water, and breaks up there.

Comment: @Alex, True. But the passuk could be talking about hail, sleet, etc. See Radak there.

Comment: Jake and Alex, I'm not sure you guys are disagreeing here. I'm getting dizzy trying to follow the discussion. But going back to my question, Jake, why would MB choose an obscure Aramaic word for freezing - and adapt it to Hebrew conjugation - to say, "water which has frozen, which they call 'eiz'" over an obscure Hebrew word for ice?

Comment: @SethJ, I would think that the hebrew word for ice, being that it could be used for frost, as in @Alex's example, is more vague than "water that froze". Also, it could be Chafetz Chaim thought that the more familiar terminology to the reader is the Aramaic term, being that it is used in the gemara, more so than קרח.

Answer (score 4):

[see](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.320.9-10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) the Shulchan Aruch O.C. 320:9-10:

> ט השלג והברד אין מרסקין אותם דהיינו לשברם לחתיכות דקות כדי שיזובו
>   מימיו אבל נותן הוא לתוך כוס של יין או מים והוא נימח מאיליו ואינו חושש
>   וכן אם הניחם בחמה או כנגד המדורה ונפשרו מותרים:   י  מותר לשבר הקרח
>   כדי ליטול מים מתחתיו:

There are three words being used in these two halachos: שלג, ברד and קרח.

שלג and ברד are used in the gemara (שבת נא) which is the source of halacha 9.

The source for the term קרח here is the sefer אבי עזרי being quoted by the מרדכי and שיבולי הלקט as sourced in the בית יוסף. And when referencing these rishonim, it doesn't seem like there's a need to explain what קרח is (the בית יוסף doesn't translate the word, etc.) In fact, in the previous halacha (about the ברד ושלג) the בית יוסף discusses all three terms in relation to each other.

So clearly at least during the times of the rishonim the word קרח meant ice.
Which means that the Mishna Berurah 301:65 could definitely have used this word if he wanted to.

Why didn't he? First off, the question is not really on the Mishnah Berurah; he's just quoting the Taz 301:12.

So why did the Taz write this way?
I don't have a definite answer. But it's possible that he wanted to describe the situation to explain why it's dangerous and why someone would need a cane. Elderly men don't walk on frozen rivers, but they would walk on an area which was wet and froze over.

So he didn't mention "ice" but rather "frozen water."

It's also possible that the Taz wanted to use the Yiddish word since that was how it was called in the vernacular and he wanted it to be understood by the common people.

Comment: Wait, what's the Yiddish word?

Comment: @SethJ איי"ז is yiddish for "ice."